# Объекты в div-е выровнены по центру. Нужно посредством javascript-jQuery сместить при клике любой из объектов в одно и тоже место

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как перемещать объекты, если они находятся в разных местах обычным выравниванием?

*HTML*:

есть `div` с классом *main*, в котором много `div`-ов.

*CSS*:

```
.main{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
.main div{
display: inline-block;
width: 60px;
height: 80px;
}
```

*jQuery* (событие при клике):

```
$(this).css({
"position": "absolute",
"margin-left": "400px",
"margin-top": "-440px",
"width": "250px",
"height": "465px",
"transition": "0.5s"
});
```

Но каждый `div` перемещается по-разному по оси *х*, а надо, чтобы они как-то перемещались в одно место.

Comment: Больше информации предоставьте

Comment: @Дмитрий правильно написал ниже, сделайте вместо "margin-left" и "margin-top", свойства "left" и "top" и всё будет как задумано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смущает в вопросе фраза:

> обычным выравниванием

Обычное выравнивание - это *css*-свойства `text-align` и `vertical-align`. С их помощью элементы в условный правый верхний угол вы не переместите.

Если речь об отступах `padding` и `margin`, то тут без вычислений не обойтись. Но вы задали родительскому `div` свойство `position: relative`, а дочерним элементам - `position: absolute`. Позиционирование дочерних элементов будет происходить относительно границ `div` с классом *main*.

Почему бы не воспользоваться таким способом:

```
$(this).css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": "0", /* элемент прилипает к верхней границе div.main */
    "right": "0", /* элемент прилипает к правой границе div.main */
    "transition": "0.5s"
});
```

Чтобы работала анимация, можно для дочерних элементов изначально прописать абсолютную позицию с фиксированными координатами.

Если это неудобно, то отступы надо вычислять:

```
$('.main > div').click(function () {
    // Позиция
    var horPos = $(this).offset().left - $('div.main').offset().left; // Вычисляем поцизию по 0X относительно родителя
    var verPos = $(this).offset().top - $('div.main').offset().top; // Вычисляем поцизию по 0Y относительно родителя

    $(this).css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "margin-top": -verPos,
        "margin-left": -horPos,
        "transition": "0.5s"
    });
});
```

Для позиционирования к правой границе надо будет играть с шириной отцов и детей.

Для сохранении позиции других элементов при перемещении можно поместить их в контейнеры с фиксированными размерами.

Для корректного возврата нужно разделить события клик-перемещение/клик-возврат и для каждого прописать свою функцию.

Comment: Анимация в таком случае не будет срабатывать как положено, т.к. изначально у элемента не было свойств `right` И `top`.